# Character Wildcard when using Java if and else if statement

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, printf, equals

I am doing an assignment at the moment where I am building a hotel invoicing application and I have to ask the user for the customers registration number for valet parking.
If NOTHING is entered it is assumed that the valet parking service is not required, but if SOMETHING is entered a $50.00 fee must be added to the displayed invoice.
The code I have so far is below and I am just trying to work out how to make this happen.

```
    if(vehiclereg.equals("SOMETHING")) {
        valetparkingsurcharge = 50; // Calculate Valet Parking Surcharge
        System.out.printf("\n%-50s %-100s\n", "Valet Parking:", "Y");
        System.out.printf("%-50s %-5s %.2f\n", "Valet Parking Surcharge:", "$", valetparkingsurcharge + " vehiclereg");
        } 
            else if (vehiclereg.equals("NOTHING")) {
            System.out.printf("\n%-50s %-100s\n", "Valet Parking Surcharge:", "N");
        }
```

I have chucked the SOMETHING and NOTHING in the code to represent where I need these 2 functions to occur so it makes it clearer for everybody else.
I have used the IF statement previously in the assignment fine however it has a YES or NO input so I figured out how to code it in. The problem with the above section is that it has to have ANY input or NO input which directs the program what to do.

Note that the valetparkingsurcharge is setup as a double and vehiclereg is setup as a string and data has been either entered (to indicate that the service is required) or not entered (to indicate that the service is not required) at the start of the program.

I have only just started Java and this is my first assignment so I would appreciate any help that anybody can give me with this section. I am just about pulling out my hair!

Pat

Comment: Beware of using a `String` comparison in this manner (`vehiclereg.equals("SOMETHING")`) as `vehiclereg` could be `null`.  You could use `"SOMETHING".equals(vehiclereg)` or if you to care about the case `"SOMETHING".equalsIgnoreCase(vehiclereg)`

Comment: This is not related to the question, but I suggest you not to use `double` to represent an amount of money. Use dedicated libraries instead, like [Joda Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for null & input length

```
if (vehiclereg != null && vehiclereg.length() > 0) {
  // charge valet parking
} else {
  // do not charge
}
```

Or for more sophisticated checking, see [Java Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: (What if the `String` is `" "` ;))

Comment: If you want more thorough, use `StringUtils.isBlank()`. It checks all of null, empty and whitespaces: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)

Comment: Not an issue for, just want to avoid the OP asking another question on the same subject ;)

Answer (score 2):

`String.isEmpty` will check if the string is an empty or not.

Alternatively you can check for `null` as well

Comment: (What if the `String` is `" "` ;))

Comment: You mean if the input is mad? :-P Well trim to the rescue then... But that should be done when getting the input from the UI... Not in the function in my opinion....

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of the `String` instead

```
if(vehiclereg != null && vehiclereg.trim().length() > 0) {
    valetparkingsurcharge = 50; // Calculate Valet Parking Surcharge
    System.out.printf("\n%-50s %-100s\n", "Valet Parking:", "Y");
    System.out.printf("%-50s %-5s %.2f\n", "Valet Parking Surcharge:", "$", valetparkingsurcharge + " vehiclereg");
} 
else { // Nothing...
    System.out.printf("\n%-50s %-100s\n", "Valet Parking Surcharge:", "N");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check it via true/false statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can further check this by adding another checker

```
 if (vehiclereg != null > vehiclereg.length() > 0) {  //prevent null pointer
      // charge valet parking (SOMETHING or NOTHING or whatever value)
     } else if(vehiclereg != null && "".equals(vehiclereg)){
       //if user enters empty strings, this can happen
     }else {
      // default operation   if conditions above are not satisfied
   }
```